# Frustration about cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Ive been looking through all the cookies related threads on here and the rest of the wonderful world of web and nothing ive found relates, unless im missing something, to what im experiencing here.

I have an aspx page that im getting a user to input data to as below:

testform.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testform.aspx.cs" Inherits="assets_testform" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Incident Druation Monitor</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="assets/images/favicon.png" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/site.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="formpage">
            <div class="header">
            </div><!-- end header -->

            <div class="form-style-10">
                <h1>Incident Duration<span>Input the details below and start the timer!</span></h1>

                <form id="frmIdm" name="frmIdm" runat="server">
                    <div class="section">Incident Details:</div>
                    <div class="inner-wrap">
                        <label>Incident Name: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtIncnam" /></label>
                        <label>Incident Location: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtIncloc" /></label>
                        <label>Incident Type: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtInctype" /></label>
                        <label>Date and Time Incident Occured: </label>
                                                <label class="sublable">Month: <asp:DropDownList name="month" runat="server" ID="ddlMonth" width="150">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select the Month" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="January" Value="Jan"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Februray" Value="Feb"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="March" Value="Mar"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="April" Value="Apr"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="May" Value="May"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="June" Value="Jun"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="July" Value="Jul"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="August" Value="Aug"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="September" Value="Sep"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="October" Value="Oct"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="November" Value="Nov"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="December" Value="Dec"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList></label>
                                                <label class="sublable">Day: <asp:DropDownList name="day" runat="server" ID="ddlDay" Width="150">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select the Day" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="01"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="02"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="03"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="04"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="05"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="06"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="07"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="08"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="9" Value="09"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="11" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="12" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="13" Value="13"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="14" Value="14"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="15" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="16" Value="16"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="17" Value="17"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="18" Value="18"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="19" Value="19"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="20" Value="20"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="21" Value="21"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="22" Value="22"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="23" Value="23"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="24" Value="24"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="25" Value="25"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="26" Value="26"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="27" Value="27"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="28" Value="28"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="29" Value="29"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="30" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Text="31" Value="31"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList></label>
                                                <label class="sublable">Year: <asp:TextBox name="year" ID="txtyear" runat="server" placeholder="2016" Width="150" /></label>
                                                <label class="sublable">Time (24hr format): <asp:TextBox name="timestart" ID="txtTimestart" runat="server" placeholder="00:00:00" Width="150" /></label>
                        <label><asp:Button Text="Start Timer" runat="server" ID="btnStart_timer" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="window.open('timer.aspx')" /></label>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function fixform() {
                            if (opener.document.getElementById("frmIdmt").target != "_blank") return;
                            opener.document.getElementById("frmIdmt").target = "";
                            opener.document.getElementById("frmIdmt").action = opener.location.href;
                        }
                    </script>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the user then clicks 'Start Timer' it is then supposed to store that data into a cookie in the CodeFile as such:

testform.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class assets_testform : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("PreviousPage");

        CookieData cd = new CookieData();
        cd.IncidentLocation = txtIncloc.Text;
        cd.IncidentDay = ddlDay.SelectedValue;
        cd.IncidentMonth = ddlMonth.SelectedValue;
        cd.IncidentName = txtIncnam.Text;
        cd.IncidentType = txtInctype.Text;
        cd.StartTime = txtTimestart.Text;
        cd.Year = txtyear.Text;

        cookie.Value = cd.ToXmlString();

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

It then passes the data onto the CookieData.cs file as below:

CookieData.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CookieData
/// </summary>
public class CookieData
{

    public String ToXmlString()
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CookieData));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        xs.Serialize(ms, this);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }

    public static CookieData FromXmlString(String XML)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CookieData));

        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(XML);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);

        return (CookieData)xs.Deserialize(ms);
    }

    public CookieData()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public String IncidentName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String IncidentType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String IncidentLocation
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String IncidentDay
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String IncidentMonth
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String Year
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String StartTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

It then should pass this data onto the target page timer.aspx as such:

timer.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="timer.aspx.cs" Inherits="timer" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
            <title>Incident Druation Monitor - Timer</title>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="idt_files/images/favicon.ico" />
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="idt_files/images/favicon.png" />
            <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="idt_files/images/favicon.png" />
            <script src="idt_files/scripts/js/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="idt_files/css/site.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="formpage">
            <div class="header">

            </div><!-- end header -->

            <div class="form-style-10">
                <h1>Incident Duration<span>The timer has started below.</span></h1>

                <form id="frmIdmt" name="frmIdm" runat="server">
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    /*
                                    * Basic Count Up from Date and Time
                                    * Author: @mrwigster / trulycode.com
                                    */
                                    $(document).ready(function () {

                                        var month = ("<%=month %>");

                                        var day = ("<%=day %>");

                                        var year = ("<%=year %>");

                                        var datestart = month + "," + day + "," + year;

                                        var timestart = ("<%=start %>");

                                        // Month,Day,Year,Hour,Minute,Second
                                        upTime(datestart + " " + timestart); // ****** Change this line!
                                    });
                                    function upTime(countTo) {
                                        now = new Date();
                                        countTo = new Date(countTo);
                                        difference = (now - countTo);

                                        days = Math.floor(difference / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1);
                                        hours = Math.floor((difference % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1);
                                        mins = Math.floor(((difference % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
                                        secs = Math.floor((((difference % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);
                                        document.getElementById('countup').setAttribute("uptime", days + ':' + hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs)
                                        document.getElementById('days').firstChild.nodeValue = days;
                                        document.getElementById('hours').firstChild.nodeValue = hours;
                                        document.getElementById('minutes').firstChild.nodeValue = mins;
                                        document.getElementById('seconds').firstChild.nodeValue = secs;

                                        clearTimeout(upTime.to);
                                        upTime.to = setTimeout(function () { upTime(countTo); }, 1000);
                                    }

                                    function stop_timer() {
                                        clearTimeout(upTime.to);
                                        var endtime = 'Days: ' + days + '. Time: ' + hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs;
                                        document.getElementById('incendtime').value = endtime;
                                        /*return;*/
                                    }
                                </script>

                    <!-- Start Incident Details  -->
                    <div runat="server" id="idmstart" style="/*display:none;*/">
                        <div class="section">Incident Duration Timer!</div>
                        <div class="inner-wrap">
                            <label>Incident Name: <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblName"></asp:Label></label>
                            <label>Incident Location: <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblLocation"></asp:Label></label>
                            <label>Incident Type: <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblType"></asp:Label></label>
                            <label>Incident Started at: <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblTime"></asp:Label></label>
                            <div id="countup">
                                <h3>Duration Time</h3>
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div id="clockdiv">
                                          <div>
                                            <span id="days">00</span>
                                            <div class="timeRefDays">Days</div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div>
                                            <span id="hours">00</span>
                                            <div class="timeRefHours">Hrs.</div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div>
                                            <span id="minutes">00</span>
                                            <div class="timeRefMinutes">Min.</div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div>
                                            <span id="seconds">00</span>
                                            <div class="timeRefSeconds">Sec.</div>
                                          </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br /><br /><br />
                            <!-- <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Stop Timer" ID="btnStop_timer" OnClientClick="stop_timer()" /> --> <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save Log" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="stop_timer()" />
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="incendtime" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Incident Details -->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

timer.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class timer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string month;
    protected string day;
    protected string year;
    protected string start;

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CookieData cd = CookieData.FromXmlString(Request.Cookies["PreviousPage"].Value);

        month = cd.IncidentMonth;
        day = cd.IncidentDay;
        year = cd.Year;
        start = cd.StartTime;

        var datestart = month + "," + day + " " + year;
        var tod = "";

        DateTime starttime = DateTime.Parse(start);

        tod = starttime.ToString("T");

        lblName.Text = cd.IncidentName;
        lblLocation.Text = cd.IncidentLocation;
        lblType.Text = cd.IncidentType;
        lblTime.Text = " " + tod;
    }

    public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        var name = lblName.Text.Replace("_", string.Empty);

        using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/agilbert/Desktop/tmp/Test_" + name + ".txt"))
        {
            var tod = "";
            var itimestart = start;

            var datestart = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

            string endtime = incendtime.Value;

            DateTime starttime = DateTime.Parse(itimestart);

            tod = starttime.ToString("T");

            objWriter.WriteLine("Incident log created: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            objWriter.WriteLine("Incident Name: " + lblName.Text);
            objWriter.WriteLine("Incident Location: " + lblLocation.Text);
            objWriter.WriteLine("Incident Type: " + lblType.Text);
            objWriter.WriteLine("Incident happend on: " + datestart);
            objWriter.WriteLine("Incident Started at: " + lblTime.Text);
            objWriter.WriteLine("Duration of incident: " + endtime);

            objWriter.Flush();
            objWriter.Close();
        }
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.close();", true);
        //Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

I dont know if i have messed something up within my code here or not but when ever i run this fully for the first time, this is with clearing the browsers currently stored cookies, i get a exception error for a null value for the cookie when it loads into the timer.aspx page.

I can then click start timer again on the testform.aspx page with no values put in and i will get the cookie values from the previous run.

What is it im missing here? Im more than sure it is something simple but i cant spot it anywhere and its slowly driving me insane.

So its clear im asking what have i done wrong in the set up of the cookie process here?

There is more but I will see if any solution can kill the second bird with one stone before i go asking a question that may be redundant.

Thanks for any help here.

**Edit:** Thanks to the advice from @khlr, i have solved the question above. Thank you to all the replied and supplied options for me to try.

**Edit 2:** Side question here is it possible to randomly generate a cookie name and then access said cookie on the next page? The reasoning for this side question is i want to be able to run multiples of the timer.aspx page at once and save the data the individual pages are showing. Or are cookies not best suited for that?

Comment: Are `OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"` and `OnClientClick="window.open('timer.aspx')"` executed simultaneously?

Comment: Try adding a specific path to the cookie where it gets created. Something like this: `cookie.Path = "/";`.

Comment: @khlr, that is a good question. I would say yes they are but i will test my code to find out.

Comment: @user1429080, I will give that a try after i figure out if the OnClick and the OnClientClick are executing together or not.

Comment: @khlr: They were executing at exactly the same time.
This was causing the issue I was facing with the Cookie not going through the first time round.
I would mark this as my answer for this question, Knew it would be something simple, but i dont think i can mark comments as answers.

Comment: I'm glad I could help 

Answer (score 2):

Cookies store strings, but not binary objects. So, you can serialize your object into strings. In order to do that, write your ToXmlString method in the class and send your obj to the method as parameter which will convert the object to string and set as cookie value

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("PreviousPage");

    CookieData cd = new CookieData();
    cd.IncidentLocation = txtIncloc.Text;
    cd.IncidentDay = ddlDay.SelectedValue;
    cd.IncidentMonth = ddlMonth.SelectedValue;
    cd.IncidentName = txtIncnam.Text;
    cd.IncidentType = txtInctype.Text;
    cd.StartTime = txtTimestart.Text;
    cd.Year = txtyear.Text;

    cookie.Value = ToXmlString(cd);

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}




public String ToXmlString(CookieData cdObj)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<string>>));
        StringWriter outSWriter = new StringWriter();
        xs.Serialize(outSWriter, cdObj);
        return outSWriter.ToString();
    }
```

Then work with your cookie. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I never got to testing or using your method but im sure that it will help someone in the same situation as me.